# nextState on componentWillUpdate not correct while testing with Jest (using also react-router wrapper)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jestjs, reactjs-testutils

I am using Jest 0.4.0. I have a component wrapped into this (from react-router docs):

```
var stubRouterContext = (Component, props, stubs) => {
  function RouterStub() { }

  Object.assign(RouterStub, {
    makePath () {},
    makeHref () {},
    transitionTo () {},
    replaceWith () {},
    goBack () {},
    getCurrentPath () {},
    getCurrentRoutes () {},
    getCurrentPathname () {},
    getCurrentParams () {},
    getCurrentQuery () {},
    isActive () {},
    getRouteAtDepth() {},
    setRouteComponentAtDepth() {}
  }, stubs)

  return React.createClass({
    childContextTypes: {
      router: React.PropTypes.func,
      routeDepth: React.PropTypes.number
    },

    getChildContext () {
      return {
        router: RouterStub,
        routeDepth: 0
      };
    },

    render () {
      return <Component {...props} />
    }
  });
};
```

My component uses `componentWillUpdate`:

```
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {something: ""};
  },
  componentWillUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    if(nextState.something === "12345"){
      this.context.router.transitionTo("MyRoute", {id: nextState.something});
    }
  },
```

In my test:

```
var ComponentWrapper = stubRouterContext(MyComponent, {});
var myComponentInstance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ComponentWrapper />);

it('expects to do something on componentWillUpdate', function(){
  myComponentInstance.setState({something: "12345"});
  expect(myComponentInstance.getChildContext().router.transitionTo.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual('MyRoute'); 
  expect(myComponentInstance.getChildContext().router.transitionTo.mock.calls[0][1]).toEqual({id: '12345'});
});
```

As much as I call `setState`, my `nextState` in `componentWillUpdate` is always `something: ""`. However, in the test, if I check the content of `myComponentInstance.state` then it is `something: "12345"`. So basically, `componentWillUpdate` gets called but not having the new state even my instance component has it.

Any ideas on this?

--

## EDIT 1

Below suggestions are based on setState being asynchronous function but that didn't solve the problem. I was also trying to simulate a store change (Flux pattern) in this way:

```
myStore.getState = jest.genMockFunction().mockImplementation(function() {
   return{
    something: "12345",
   };
});

myComponentInstance.onChange(); //Simulate store change (this function has setState inside taking values from the store)
```

Well that didn't work either, actually was telling me that `onChange` is not defined. So my problem is with the react-router wrapper. I found a solution but I am not sure if there are better ones cause this one looks very hacky. It is the following:

```
var RouterWrapper = stubRouterContext(Component, {ref: "myRealComponentInstance"});
var renderedComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<RouterWrapper />);
var myComponentInstance = renderedComponent.refs.myRealComponentInstance;
```

In this way, both `myComponentInstance.setState` or simulating a `myComponentInstance.onChange` mocking the store work and I don't need to use asynchronous functions.

Comment: Have you found a solution to that? I also have a problem where inside componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState), my nextState is already equal to this.state. I can't quite catch the moment when state changes with this lifecycle method.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution to my problem here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setSate is an asychronous function so you need to use the callback as shown below:

```js
myComponentInstance.setState({something: "12345"}, function() {
  expect(myComponentInstance.getChildContext().router.transitionTo.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual('MyRoute');
  expect(myComponentInstance.getChildContext().router.transitionTo.mock.calls[0][1]).toEqual({
    id: '12345'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

setState is often asynchronous and cannot be relied upon being synchronous at all.  You need to pass it a function callback for the second argument if you want to check that the state actually changed.

Put your expect calls inside the callback and you should be fine.